# Make git commit using sudo

Tags: linux, git

How can one make a git commit of a folder where they don't have write access?  My initial attempt was:

```
normaluser@host:/etc $ sudo git init
normaluser@host:/etc $ sudo git commit -m'init'
```

Unfortunately, this will not work.  The regular user has a `.gitconfig` with the required name and email and I need to have git use those credentials in the commit.  The root user does not have such git credentials, and therefore cannot make a commit.

Comment: Are you sure? If I do `sudo git config -l --show-origin` it still shows me the config values for my user, not for root.

Comment: @Vampire  It doesn't do so for me.  Note that `--show-origin` resulted in error, but `sudo git config -l` shows roots credentials (which I had recently added before getting ΔλЛ's answer)

Comment: You then maybe should update your Git version. `--show-origin` exists since version 2.8.0. That means your version is more than 1.5 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git has `-c` option that let's you override values set in `.gitconfig` (or provide any new key-value pairs):

```
   -c <name>=<value>
       Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will override
       values from configuration files. The <name> is expected in the same format as
       listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).
```

So you could for example execute:

```
git -c user.name=user1032531 init
```

You could also link your user's `.gitconfig` as root's gitconfig or make the grant the current user access to all the files that need to be in the repo (consider using the last option).

Comment: So, something like `sudo git -c user.name=user1032531 -c user.email=user@stack.com init`, `sudo git -c user.name=user1032531 -c user.email=user@stack.com add .`, `sudo git -c user.name=user1032531 -c user.email=user@stack.com commit -m'init'`?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, you may just create an alias: `alias git='git -c user.name=user1032531 -c user.email=user@stack.com'`.

Comment: Ah, alias is better!

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options here, either you give yourself permissions to that folder (i.e make it usable by anyone), you can change the directory of what you are trying to commit to somewhere where you do have perms, or you can edit git's config file for the sudo editing the file using sudo.

Comment: How can one change the directory to where it is committed?

Comment: not to where it is commited, change the directory of where the file you are trying to commit is, unless I misread your question. If I did, sorry

Comment: Besides, the other answer is better than mine, follow @ΔλЛ answer

Answer (score 2):

To automatically pull in my non-root user's config files, I use the `bash` alias:

```
alias gsudo='sudo git -c "include.path='"${XDG_CONFIG_DIR:-$HOME/.config}/git/config\" -c \"include.path=$HOME/.gitconfig\""
```

Then I use `gsudo` instead of `git` to both:

- Run as root
- Have access to all non-root user git configuration

Check that the config is indeed being imported:

```
gsudo config --list --show-origin --includes | less
```